# Get from IList<Dictionary<string,object>> keys which exist in all dictionaries from IList

Tags: c#, linq

For example in IList i have three dictionaries with following keys :

**dictionary 1** keys:

aaa

aaa1

aaa2

**dictionary 2** keys:

aaa

aaa1

bbb3

bbb4

**dictionary 3** keys:

aaa

bbb3

bbb4

In result i need get the following list of keys using LINQ:

aaa

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

```
var result = list
    .SelectMany(l => l.Keys)
    .Distinct()
    .Where(k => list.All(l => l.ContainsKey(k)))
    .ToList();
```

Or to build on @ken2k solution (which might have better performance):

```
var duplicatedKeys = myList
    .SelectMany(z => z.Keys)
    .GroupBy(z => z)
    .Where(z => z.Count() == myList.Count) //Number of items in group should be equal to the number of dictionaries in the list
    .Select(z => z.Key) 
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

A `GroupBy` should be enough to isolate the groups of keys that contain more than one element:

```
var duplicatedKeys = myList
    .SelectMany(z => z.Keys)    // Flattens the keys to a unique IEnumerable
    .GroupBy(z => z)            // Group keys by key
    .Where(z => z.Count() > 1)  // Get groups with more than 1 occurence
    .Select(z => z.Key)         // Get the actual key
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's the same like just a var  duplicatedKeys = myList
    .SelectMany(z => z.Keys).Distinct(); 
I get all keys from all of dictionaries.
I need get only that keys which repeated  in all of dictionaries.

Comment: This solution will return keys that exist in two or more dictionaries. OP wants to get keys that exist in *all* dictionaries.

Comment: @YacoubMassad The OP's question was modified after I posted this answer. The initial example stated `aaa1` should be returned but it wasn't present in all dictionaries.

Comment: I see. I Didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
var duplicates = list
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Keys)
                   .Where(x => !set.Add(x));
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.